# Confusion about the scope table in Maven dependency scope

Tags: maven, maven-2

In [Transitive Scope Table](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) most seems to be reasonable according to the definition of each scope: compile, provided, runtime, test. Except for two combinations I am fully confused by the result. Both are under runtime column of the Transitive Scope Table, one for the provided row, one for the test row.

Suppose A depend on B under scope test, and B depend on C under scope runtime, that means B should in test classpath to compile A or run unit test of A, and C should in test classpath to run unit test of B; So with my understanding, C should only appear in test classpath to run unit test of A, but no need to appear in test classpath to compile A, so it seems the result should be "A depend on C under scope runtime, not test".

Similarly if A depend on B under scope provided, and B depend on C under scope runtime, that means B should in test classpath to compile A, and B should be provided by JDK or containers to run unit test of A, and C should in test classpath to run unit test of B; So with my understanding, C should in test classpath to run unit test of A, no matter C is provided by JDK or containers, or explicitly available in test classpath, but no need to appear in test classpath to compile A, thus the result could be runtime(though runtime could not indicate the meaning of provided by JDK or containers, but I could not find other more reasonable scope), but not provided.

Maybe I miss some important knowledge that I don't know. I am newbie to Maven, so anyone know why the document say the result should be provided and test?

Comment: I am confused by your argumentation: In the second case, why should "provided" and "runtime" influence the test class path?

Comment: Don't know your precise question. what you mentioned "test class path" in compile time or in execution time(run unit test)? According to the definition of provided and runtime:
provided: This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, but it indicate the container or JDK will provide in execution time.
runtime: It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath. That means it applies to the test classpath for execution phase.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose A depend on B under scope test, and B depend on C under scope runtime, that means B should in test classpath to compile A or run unit test of A, and C should in test classpath to run unit test of B; So with my understanding, C should only appear in test classpath to run unit test of A, but no need to appear in test classpath to compile A, so it seems the result should be "A depend on C under scope runtime, not test".

B has scope `test`, C has scope `test`*`runtime`=`test`.

> Similarly if A depend on B under scope provided, and B depend on C under scope runtime, that means B should in test classpath to compile A,

As `provided`, B is in both compile and test classpaths.

> and B should be provided by JDK or containers to run unit test of A, and C should in test classpath to run unit test of B;

Running tests of B is irrelevant if we speak of A. But if the environment provides B then it should also provide runtime dependencies of B, thus C.

> So with my understanding, C should in test classpath to run unit test of A, no matter C is provided by JDK or containers, or explicitly available in test classpath, but no need to appear in test classpath to compile A, thus the result could be runtime(though runtime could not indicate the meaning of provided by JDK or containers, but I could not find other more reasonable scope), but not provided.

You basically wonder why `provided`*`runtime`=`provided`. Technically I think you're right, `runtime` scope would be sufficient. The problem is semantics. `provided` means it is provided by the container, so if C is a runtime dependency of provided dependency `B`, it is also provided by the container. Which is better expressed by `provided`.

Practically it is not usual for typical `provided` dependencies to have some `runtime` dependencies. `provided` dependencies are normally some kind of APIs, `runtime` dependencies are normally implementations. So having `runtime` dependency for `provided` dependency basically diminishes the whole idea of separating API and implementation. Then why have two artifacts in first place?

Comment: Thanks. Since you put most explanation on the second case, I am fully understand your meaning. I didn't realize the fact "if environment provides B then it should also provide runtime dependencies of B, thus C". Just one more question, I think I have misunderstand the meaning of provided. Document say "provided only available on the compilation and test classpath", does it mean it's available on compilation of normal source code and compilation of test code", or it mean it's just available on compilation of test code? Previously I think it's the later meaning.

Comment: For the first case,I still don't know the reason.My understanding is A depend on B in test scope, means B should in compilation of test code as well as in runtime of unit test. B depend on C in runtime, then C will only in runtime of B, and no need during compilation of B. So when compilation of test code of A, I think it don't need C, that's why I think test * runtime should not be test, because test scope means compilation of test code of A still needs C,which is not right. I think the result should be runtime, because that means A need C only during runtime,but not compilation of test code.

Comment: "does it mean it's available on compilation of normal source code and compilation of test code", or it mean it's just available on compilation of test code?"  
Both, of course.

Comment: Well for the first case what should `test`*`runtime` give otherwise if not `test`? If you say `runtime` this will mean that A depends on C in the runtime which is not true and harmful because you get a runtime dependency which you definitely not need. `test` scope of C might be not 100% correct but it is not harmful as it does not influence productive use of A.

Comment: I think I understand the difference between test and runtime.Previously I only know both require dependency appear in the execution phase. Actually runtime indicate the dependent itself require the dependency, but test indicate the extra test code incur this dependency. I guess when create assembly, maven will include runtime dependency, but not test dependency. Am I right?

Comment: @Audison If with "assembly" you mean shaded jar or likes then yes, `runtime` will be there, `test` will not.